# Mini-Max Sum Hacker Rank

Tags: java, array

```
 package solution;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.security.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.concurrent.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;

 public class Solution {

// Complete the miniMaxSum function below.
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
    int suma = 0;
    int num = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    num = arr[i];
    suma = suma + num;
}
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println((suma-arr[arr.length-1]) + " " + (suma-arr[0]));
}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];

    String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
        arr[i] = arrItem;
    }

    miniMaxSum(arr);

    scanner.close();
 }
}
```

Ese es el codigo completo del ejercicio ya con mi solución en el.

Pero si se ponen estos valores: **`256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071625`**.

En la ultima suma **`2063136757 + 938071625 me da = -1293758914`** !!!! no entiendo porque, ya lo debugue y todo va bien pero al sumar esas cantidades me da ese resultado!!!

Lo raro es que con el valor minimo **`256741038`**, cuando le resto **`-1293758914 - 256741038`**, si me da el valor correcto del ejercicio que es **`2063136757`**. Pero con el valor máximo me da **`-1550499952`**.

Se supone que los **outputs** esperados son **`2063136757 2744467344`**

Answer (score 0):

Es porque `2,744.467.344` es un valor muy grande como para almacenarlo en los bytes de un tipo de dato `int`.

Puedes solucionarlo simplemente utilizando el tipo de dato primitivo `long` en vez del `int`.

```
tipo        tam. bytes       rango

byte        1 byte           -128 a 127
short       2 bytes          -32,768 a 32,767
int         4 bytes          -2,147.483.648 a 2,147.483.647
long        8 bytes          -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 a 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
float       4 bytes          ±3.40282347E+38F (Aproximadamente)
double      8 bytes          ±1.79769313486231570E+308 (Aproximadamente)
char        2 bytes          0 a 65,536
boolean     (1 bit)          true o false
```